# Django "page not found 404"

Tags: python, django, web, frameworks

I have a problem with Django he is saying that my urls don't match each other when they indeed do (or I'm blind). I've already tried with same questions answered here, of those solutions dind't worked out.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/

Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^music/ r^$ [name='index']

The current URL, music/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

website\urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

views.py:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>This is the Music app homepage')
```

music.urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url('r^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `music.urls`

`'r^$'` should be `r'^$'`

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't see that.

Comment: @Francesco LOL! Thanks, bro..., for real T.T Thank you!